# How fill unstinting numeric values in df column

Tags: python, pandas

so I am trying to add rows to data frame that should follow a numeric order 1 to 52

but my data is missing numbers, so I need to add these rows and fill these spots with NaN values or null.

```
df = pd.DataFrame("Weeks": [1,2,3,15,16,20,21,52],
   "Values": [10,10,10,10,50,60,70,40])
```

Desired output:

```
Weeks         Values
1              10
2              10
3              10
4              NaN
5              NaN
6              NaN
7              NaN
8              NaN
...
52             40

and so on until it reach Weeks = 52
```

My solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame("Weeks": "" , "Values":"")

for x in range(1,53):

    for i in df.Weeks:
        if x == i:
            new_df["Weeks"] = x
            new_df["Values"] = df.Values[i]
```

The problem it is super inefficient, anyone know a way to do it in much efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the `Weeks` as index an [`reindex`](https://www.google.com/search?q=padas+reindex&oq=padas+reindex&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.1436j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with a `range` up to the maximum week:

```
df.set_index('Weeks').reindex(range(1,df.Weeks.max()))
```

Or accounting for the minimum week too:

```
df.set_index('Weeks').reindex(range(*df.Weeks.agg(('min', 'max'))))

        Values
Weeks        
1        10.0
2        10.0
3        10.0
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11        NaN
12        NaN
13        NaN
14        NaN
15       10.0
16       50.0
17        NaN
...
```